# Shiny - How can I tell when graphs are done rendering programmatically?

Tags: r, shiny

I am an old hand at R, but new to Shiny. (It is very cool!)

I am rendering graphs using ggplot2 in Shiny, and it works great. The only thing is that after my ggplot executes and I issue a renderPlot, there is a delay before the graphs display. I am fine with the delay, but I would like to know in the program after the graphs render. I hit the bottom of my code and the graphs are still rendering in the background.

Any advice is appreciated.

Lou

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: The server section of a Shiny app doesn't always calculate from top to bottom. You can add print statements inside your various blocks of code in the server section to see when they calculate.

Comment: Ahh,  me being an old guy that grew up in a top down programming world, I just assumed that was the case. I will use some print statements for a debug. I’ll also try to get a snippet of my code here. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinybusy/vignettes/shinybusy-usage.html

Check this out! You can add a busy spinner and then every time your graph is being rendered, you will be able to understand with the indicator.